# search in json and give the result as json for likely string values in php

Tags: php, json

I have a set json data. In that i have to return a json with key and value pair in php.
I used the json as follows

```
[{
  "id": "1995",
  "name": "Banahatti"
},
{
  "id": "5074",
  "name": "Kolhapur(Maharashtra)"
},
{
  "id": "2356",
  "name": "Bmbur"
},
{
  "id": "906",
  "name": "Ammla"
},
{
  "id": "536",
  "name": "Puttur"
},
{
  "id": "1308",
  "name": "Poogolam"
},
{
  "id": "1217",
  "name": "Sarangpur"
},
{
  "id": "826",
  "name": "Hiriyur"
},
{
  "id": "24911",
  "name": "Himmatnagar"
},
{
  "id": "3993",
  "name": "Podili"
}]
```

In this json values , i have to search and get json ,if i give a name value is starting with `B` means i have to get result json as follows

```
   [{
      "id": "1995",
      "name": "Banahatti"
    },

    {
      "id": "2356",
      "name": "Bmbur"
    }]
```

How can i able to achieve this In php.

Answer (score 0):

PHP knows nothing about JSON, I would convert it into an array and then use array_filter, and then convert it back to JSON.  Not super effecient, but certainly better than trying something like a regex.  Something like the following:

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$res = array_filter($arr, function($val) { 
   return substr($val['name'],0,1) == 'B';
});
$newJson = json_encode($res);
```

Comment: Well said . I did as per your answer but i m getting `Notice: Undefined offset: 0`. In closure function what is the use of `$val`.

Comment: I guess it depends on which PHP you are using, some allow array access to strings, some you have to cast to a string, probably better to use substr...

Comment: Close, but you need to treat `$val` as the the associative array that it is, not as a string (i.e. `return substr($val['name'],0,1) == 'B';`.

Answer (score 0):

`array_filter()` is a good option here. Just check every array object's `name` property for a substring match.  That might look like this:

```
$array = json_decode($input_json);
$search_term = 'B'; // populate your search value into this variable
$filtered_array = array_filter($array, function($obj) use ($search_term) {
    // if you need to search any part of string
    return strlen(strstr($obj->name, $search_term));
}
$filtered_json = json_encode($filtered_array);
```

Note, that this will search for your string in any part of the `name` property.  If you want to search only from the beginning, you can use the following inside the array_filter function:

```
return (strpos($obj->name, $search_term) === 0);
```